# Task.Delay() does not delay

Tags: c#

Trying to understand async/await in the sample below:

```
public static Task <string> job()
{
    Console.WriteLine("start delay 1");
    Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("sleep done 1");
    Task<string> t =  new Task<string>(()=> {
        Console.WriteLine("start delay 2");
        Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("sleep done 2");
        return "aaaa"; }) ;
    t.Start();
    return t;

}



public async static void caller()
{
    string s = await job();
    Console.WriteLine("result is {0}", s);

}



public static void Main()
{

    caller();
    Console.WriteLine("done with caller");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To get a more clear picture I would like to make task run a bit longer and I have added Task.Delay(). Both delays are taking no time and finish immediately. Why? How to make my task spend some time on simple job to make it last longer?

Comment: you have to `await` `Task.Delay(ms)` (Note you have to make job() `async` as @stuartd said for this to work)

Comment: `job()` should also be marked as `async`

Comment: have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) and the code example there

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Delay` creates a Task that delays for the time specified. You do spawn a Task that Delays for 2 Seconds but you never wait for it.

adding `await` to the call does fix this. (You have to mark the method `async`)

```
public static async Task <string> job()
{
    ...
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    ...
}
```

You can read more about Asynchronous Programming [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score 0):

Task.Delay returns you a task that will complete in the given milliseconds you have provided. To hold execution of your code at this point (this is a massive simplification of what it does and you should definately do more learning on async/await in c#) you need to await the call to Task.Delay(2000) like this

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

to use the await key word you need to mark your method signature as async like this

```
public static async Task<string> job()
```

but I would highly recommend reading up on async and await